# Can a vue component know if a listener is listening?

Tags: vue.js

Say I have a modal dialogue as a Vue component. Sometimes I want OK and Cancel. Sometimes, I just want OK. The cleanest way I can think to do this would be for my component to only display Cancel when it's caller is listening for cancel events. Can this be done?

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8rrcubk/)**

**markup**

```
<div id="vue-root">
  <confirm-modal v-on:ok="handleOk"></confirm-modal>
  <confirm-modal v-on:ok="handleOk" v-on:cancel="handleCancel"></confirm-modal>
</div>
```

**code**

```
Vue.component('confirm-modal',{
    template : `
    <div class="confirm-modal">
        Are you sure<br>
      <button v-on:click="$emit('ok',{})">OK</button>
      <button v-if="'HOW DO I TEST IF CANCEL WILL BE CAPTURED???'" v-on:click="$emit('cancel',{})">Cancel</button
    </div>
  `,
})
vm = new Vue({
    el : '#vue-root',
  methods : {
    handleOk : function(){
        alert('OK already');
    },
    handleCancel : function(){

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: when you want just OK and when OK and Cancel just v-if the CANCEL button when you match your logic

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this, you can pass props from parent to child component when you want to show ok and cancel button.
Here you have some more about props
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Answer (score 0):

First you can emit an event without value and the parent will catch it. You dont need this empty Object.

What i understood from your question is this:

If you to track in confirm-modal component if the cancel button is clicked ?

Then do this.

```
Vue.component('confirm-modal',{
    template : `
    <div class="confirm-modal">
        Are you sure<br>
      <button v-on:click="$emit('ok',{})">OK</button>
      <button v-if="isCaptured" v-on:click="cancelClick">Cancel</button
    </div>
  `,
    data: function () {
      return {
          isCaptured: false,
       }; 
    },

    methods: {
       cancelClick: function() {
              this.isCaptured = true;
              // or this.$emit('cancel'); then pass prop from parent
         },
     }
})
vm = new Vue({
    el : '#vue-root',
  methods : {
    handleOk : function(){
        alert('OK already');
    },
    handleCancel : function(){

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It's not quite that. I want to catch in the component, when it's first rendered, if in the markup that called it, or somewhere else, a listener has been attached for cancel events the component will emit.

Comment: can't understand the problem, can you explain a use case of your problem so i can understand it better